# WorkManager is not initialized

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager, illegalstateexception

I got this error on sentry panel only on production build variant.

> IllegalStateException WorkManager is not initialized properly.  You
> have explicitly disabled WorkManagerInitializer in your manifest, have
> not manually called WorkManager#initialize at this point, and your
> Application does not implement Configuration.Provider.
>
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor in runWorker at line 1167

unlike the error i have no work manager dependency in project
could anyone help ...thanks in advance

Comment: Could you have some inner dependency (library) that may be using a WorkManager?

Comment: @tomerpacific I know that i dont use dependency directly in my build.gradle app. How could find out? Should i check one by one?

Comment: Share you app level gradle file here…

Comment: Show your manifest, - you are probably disabling `androidx-startup` completely,  if your own manifest doesn't show anything about `androidx-startup` also looking at your merged manifest can show if another dependency has disabled `androidx-startup`. This will affect any dependencies that rely on initialisation.  You can also view dependencies using `./gradlew dependencies` to see the dependency tree.

Comment: If suppose you using any third party libraries you can it on thier github docs or github readme…

Comment: @Mark I did not disable androidx-startup in manifest and merged manifest
And it doesn't exist in my code at all.
Got dependency tree but found no work manager ...this is the screen shot
https://imgur.com/a/wFRXBW8

Comment: Your dependecy tree shows that it has a dependency on `androidx.work:work-runtime` whch has a depedency on `androidx.startup` (can't see the parent dependency from the screen shot though) .. as I say somewhere in your manifest or merged manifest it has been disabled, which is what the error states. For work manager reference on initialsation : https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/custom-configuration